# Vertical alignment of fonts of different sizes on same line

Tags: fonts, xetex, vertical-alignment, fontsize

In XeTeX, if I have a line with two font sizes, how can I arrange to have the smaller font aligned to either the center or top of the line?

e.g.

```
\newfontinstance\biggoth[Color=000000,Scale=5.0]{Cloister Black}
\newfontinstance\smallgoth[Color=000000,Scale=2.0]{Cloister Black}


\biggoth Hello \smallgoth World
```

The "Hello" aligns to the bottom of the line.

I'm grateful for any thoughts and input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In general, TeX keeps the baselines of all characters (and boxes) at the same height. For a single word, you can do what chl suggested and raise the text using `\raisebox`. Rather than guessing at how much to raise it, you can put the word in a box (perhaps with a strut), measure its height, and then raise it appropriately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\raiseup[1]{%
        \begingroup
        \setbox0\hbox{\tiny\strut #1}%
        \leavevmode
        \raise\dimexpr \ht\strutbox - \ht0\box0
        \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
Here's some text. Here's a raised \raiseup{word}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to crop your image.

Comment: @Hendrik: Yeah, I just used Troy Henderson's LaTeX Previewer to generate it before going to bed.

Comment: @TH (+1) Great! I wondered how easy it should be to get box height. Here it is...

Comment: @chl: TeX has `\ht` for height, `\dp` for depth, and `\wd` for width. Width is obvious. Height is the height above the baseline, depth is the distance below the baseline. All are (normally) nonnegative numbers. You can also set any of them: `\wd0=3in` for example, sets the width of box 0 to 3 inches.

Comment: This solution seems not exactly correct; the top of the 'd' in "word" lies above the top of the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you can just play with `\raisebox`, e.g.

```
\biggoth Hello \raisebox{.5ex}{\smallgoth World}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is another possibility, very similar to TH.'s suggestion:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontinstance\biggoth[Color=000000,Scale=5.0]{Cloister Black}
\newfontinstance\smallgoth[Color=000000,Scale=2.0]{Cloister Black}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newcommand*{\tlap}[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{#1}%
  \raisebox{-\ht\mybox}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
}
\newcommand*{\mlap}[1]{%
  \sbox{\mybox}{#1}%
  \raisebox{-0.5\ht\mybox}{\usebox{\mybox}}%
}
\begin{document}
\tlap{\biggoth Hello}
\tlap{\smallgoth World}

\mlap{\biggoth Hello}
\mlap{\smallgoth World}
\end{document}
```

[image]