# vertically align texts of different sizes and allow line breaks

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-breaking, fontsize, raise

I would like to vertically align texts of different sizes in `latex` (`xelatex`). For example, `normal {\footnotesize small} normal` does base-line alignment, while I want center-align. I know I can use `\lower` or `\raisebox` for small chunks, but I want to **allow line breaks** too. As I want this functionality very often in texts of various lengths, I would like a macro. How could I do it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

I have notes {\footnotesize (footnote-size, too low)}.
Want to raise it {\lower-.2ex\hbox{\footnotesize (like this)}} a bit
{\footnotesize (but I want to allow for line break)}. How could I do this?

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've read [Vertical alignment of fonts of different sizes on same line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7675/vertical-alignment-of-fonts-of-different-sizes-on-same-line) but the answers rely on boxes which don't allow line breaks. I've also read [Something like \raisebox that respects line breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49179/something-like-raisebox-that-respects-line-breaks) but I'm not sure if there is an answer.

Comment: you could raise each letter separately but that would break all kerning and ligatures. If you are prepared to accept breaks just between words you could separately `\raise` (or `\lower` as you have it) each word and have the word spaces outside to allow line breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1{{\footnotesize\xfoo#1 \xfoo}}
\def\xfoo#1 #2{%
\raisebox{.3ex}{#1}%
\ifx\xfoo#2\expandafter\@gobble
\else\expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
{ \xfoo#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

I have notes  \foo{(footnote-size, too low)}.
Want to raise it \foo{(like this)} a bit
\foo{(but I want to allow for line break)}. How could I do this?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing! I confirm it works. Thanks. Now time to understand your codes.

Comment: So David, you implemented what you suggested in your first comment. Superb!